# AS3 iOS : Loading external swf

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to load a swf in another using AIR3.6.
I duplicated the code I found here http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/ but in vain. It does'nt work.
So I think I didn't understand part of the procedure.

That what I have done :

• I have a first fla I can correctly publish for iOS.

• In this fla I have this code :

```
        var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
        var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.swf");
        var _lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
        mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);

        mLoader.load(mRequest);
        function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
        {
            addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
        }
```

• In the publish settings I went to the General tab and I included my second swf : test.swf

• The second swf (test.swf). I published it with AIR 3.6 for iOS. 
It has no actionscript at all. There is only a green shape in it.

• When I test my first fla, the second one is correctly loaded.

• When I publish it in my iPad, the second swf is NOT loaded.

Can someone tells me where I was wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, 10 seconds after publishing my question, I found my solution.
I only forgot to put the _lc:LoaderContext in the mLoader.load().
So here is it :

```
    var mLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    var mRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.swf");
    var _lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
    mLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);

    mLoader.load(mRequest, _lc);
    function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event)
    {
        addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
    }
```

Note to moderators : Not sure this will be helpfull for anyone, but I don't know how to delete a post.

Comment: answering your own question is fine (and to be encouraged) - its still useful info for others